# How to pass a parameter to JSF dataTable's value attribute

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, primefaces, facelets

In a JSF 2.1 application, I need to build a JSF `dataTable` (using PrimeFaces) that shows only the db records belonging to the logged in user.

So, I need to pass the username to the bean associated to the dataTable's `value` attribute:

```
value="#{tableBuilder.records}"
```

Here is the table bean:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class TableBuilder {
    private List<MyRecord> records;
    private String username;
    // getters and setters
}
```

It's useful to know that the application consists of a single web page, with container-managed authentication implemented through `LoginBean`, a SessionScoped ManagedBean. This implies the additional effort of notifying to TableBuilder when the user logs in.

The only way I am thinking of is to inject the `LoginBean` into the `TableBuilder` through `@ManagedProperty` annotation, and checking on every request of `getRecords` if the username property of LoginBean has changed.

Maybe there are better ways?

Comment: So, it's in your webapp possible that the logged-in user get changed in between the initial request of a view and a successful postback to the very same view?

Comment: Correct. It's possible that a first user logs in, then logs out, then another user logs in using the same web page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your environment supports EL 2.2 (your question history confirms Java EE 6), then "just do it":

```
<h:dataTable value="#{bean.getModel(user)}">
```

with

```
public List<Item> getModel(User user) {
    // ...
}
```

Whether it's the right way or there are better ways, I'll leave in the middle. Keep in mind that a getter is invoked as many times as EL evaluates the value expression.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But where and how am I supposed to give a value to `user` in the web page?

Comment: Just as in my answer? The `#{user}` represents the currently logged-in user.

Comment: @BalusC So, in this special case it is 'ok' to fill the list in the getter?

Comment: @Alexander: if you get lazy loading right and thus make sure that the service method isn't unnecessarily invoked during every iteration round or even during every postback, then yes. It isn't the getter itself that is the major problem, but the efficiency (and clean code).